# Uncaught referenceError google is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

Please help me debug why Chrome is not recognizing google.
I get this error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined

I have moved the API script to the top, fail.
I adjusted my own code to match Google's documentation, fail. 
Is it Chrome that is causing my problem?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>weather map</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    html, body {
        margin: 0;
    }
    #map-canvas {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <h1>Map Test</h1>
        <div id="map-canvas">
        </div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);
        });

        var map; 
        function initMap() {        
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-    canvas"), {
                center: {lat: 29.423017, lng: -98.48527},
                zoom: 8,
            });
        }
    </script>
    <script async defer 
        src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_KEY_WAS_HERE_&callback=initMap">
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does the console tell you which line of code is causing the reference error?

Comment: try removing "defer" from your script tag. The defer prevents the script tag from executing until the DOM is parsed. And since your $(document).ready function appears before the script tag it tries to execute first. Alternatively move your script tag for maps.googleapis above the $(document).ready function.

Comment: Vincent, it says this line is the problem:  <br> google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);

Answer (score 1):

You are loading the Google Maps Javascript API asynchronously.  You can't use any of its methods until the `initMap` (callback) function runs.

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/c0fk0o9x/2/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var map;

function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), {
    center: {
      lat: 29.423017,
      lng: -98.48527
    },
    zoom: 8
  });
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
#map-canvas {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap">
</script>
<div id="container" style="height:100%; width:100%;">
  <h1>Map Test</h1>
  <div id="map-canvas"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't put your google maps event in `$(document).ready();` since window.load already registers an event listener and that should be enough.

Your google maps script tag should also be above your JavaScript code and the event listener should also be moved beneath the function.

```
<script async defer 
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_KEY_WAS_HERE_&callback=initMap">
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var map; 
    function initMap() {        
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-    canvas"), {
            center: {lat: 29.423017, lng: -98.48527},
            zoom: 8,
            });
        }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);
</script>
```

Next time you should read the documentation more thoroughly.